# css3 animation isn't applied when using @keyframes

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to animate a div to fall down from above.
Not sure why this doesn't work...

```
<div>foobar</div>

@keyframes slidein-low {
  from {
     top: 0;
     }
  to {
        top: 80%;
    }
}

div {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-name: slidein-low;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MMF52/

Answer (score 1):

First, to use *percentages* you must add:

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
}
```

For *webkit* browsers you must add the `-webkit` prefix:

```
@-webkit-keyframes slidein-low {
  from {
     top: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 80%;
  }
}
```

And for *animations* just add the required **prefix**:

```
animation-duration: 3s;
animation-name: slidein-low;
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
-webkit-animation-name: slidein-low;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MMF52/4/)

Just a side note, `animation` won't work in IE9 or less - [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 @keyframes slidein-low {
      from {
         top: 0px;
         }
      to {
            top: 100px;
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes slidein-low  /* Safari and Chrome */
    {
      from {
         top: 0px;
         }
      to {
            top: 100px;
        }
    }

    div {
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        position:relative;
        animation:slidein-low 5s infinite;
    -webkit-animation:slidein-low 5s infinite; /* Safari and Chrome */
    }
```

[ref](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it was just an oversight when you put the fiddle together, but it looks like you just left out the `position`

Adding any position other than static (absolute, relative, fixed) seems to get it working in Firefox.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MMF52/5/)**

```
div {
    position: relative; /* missing bit */
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    animation: slidein-low 3s; /* optional animation shorthand */
}
```

Comment: @chovy its in the question, but not in the fiddle

Comment: i added to fiddle, still didn't animate in chrome.

Comment: @chovy it seems chrome is a little more touchy, as stated Vucho's answer you will need to add the webkit prefix and set a height for html and body http://jsfiddle.net/MMF52/8/